# Symfony not editable form field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to Symfony, and Im wondering whether there is a build in way to show a not editable input field within a form.(not hidden, not editable, so it just appears in a box)

I am using `echo_field` and doctrine model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set the read_only attribute to true when you make the form.

```
$builder->add('dueDate', 'text', array('read_only' => true));
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/text.html#read-only

Comment: And is this possibe to set at the sfWidgetFormInputText? `$this->setWidgets(array(
      'id'   => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
      'body' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(),

      'name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('read_only' =>true)),
      'lang' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
    ));`

Comment: @user1279563 you can do what you are doing but it this way: 'name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(),array('readonly' =>true)). you write readonly wrong. i guess its because of that it doesn't work for you

Comment: In symfony 3.4 it is:
`$builder->add('dueDate', 'text', array('disabled' => true));`